Gradient flow through sampled tokens when training RNNs (but without teacher forcing)
Suppose we want to train an autoregressive generative language model based on a recurrent neural network (RNN) architecture without teacher forcing:
At each timestep, the RNN takes an input token $x_t$ and computes an output vector $o_t$, and based on $o_t$, in the forward pass we sample an output token $y_t$ that is used as input $x_{t+1}=y_t$ at the next timestep. With typical RNNs, the RNN also has a hidden state $h_t$ that is updated between timesteps.
So during training, we have a gradient flow back from timestep $t+1$ to $t$ through the hidden states from $h_{t+1}$ to $h_t$ that is used to optimize the weights (backprop. through time, BPTT). But since we do not use teacher forcing, isn't there also another (non-differentiable) 'information' flow back through the sampled token from $x_{t+1}=y_t$ to the previous timestep? And doesn't the choice of the sampled token also influence how the weights should be optimized ideally?
I am aware that teacher forcing, which provides fixed inputs $x_t$ (due to supervised learning) at each timestep, is virtually always the preferred way to train in such a scenario, and it implicitly avoids this additional path of information flow. However, the arguments used in favor of teacher forcing always revolve around preventing accumulative errors over time or training efficiency, but I have never seen any argument discussing the issue with sampled tokens being another path of information that can affect the optimal weight updates.
In the context of adversarial training where some adversary is based on the sampled tokens, I have seen workarounds such as the Gumbel Softmax trick to obtain a differentiable approximation, but again, it seems nobody discusses the issue with just RNNs used for generative language modelling.

I would be interested to know if you came across anything since you posted this. I completely agree. I was training an autoregressive RNN in the manner you described as part of my Masters research and was puzzled by the lack of information surrounding autoregressive training with BPTT, in particular how the extra output-to-hidden connection induced by autoregression may affect training. In theory, I believe enabling the gradient to flow through such a connection allows for utilizing the full potential of the RNN since since not all temporal properties of the processed sequence is compressed in
